# Python speedtest.net, or equivalent

Tags: python, networking

Is there a library for python that implements the SpeedTest.net test, or an equivalent test of internet connection speed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a project on GitHub called [SpeedCheck](https://github.com/teeks99/speed_check). It will go and fetch a given URL (defaults to [SoftLayer](http://lg.softlayer.com/)) and reports the average transfer rate in bytes per second.

When I run it:

```
python SpeedCheck.py
http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test500.zip 60 0 1024 0.5 None True False
6.16535544395e-05 , 1024
0.179219538346 , 519029
0.131760507822 , 1038058
0.218291172758 , 2076116
0.623112553731 , 4152232
0.0 , 4152232
3323051.00679
```

This means that my average speed was 3323051 B/s, or 3.169 MB/s. Checking my network transfer rate while the test was running, it looks correct.

This is for download speeds only. You could probably do something similar for uploading, but you would need to find a well-distributed server that allows posting test uploads to measure the speed. I'm not aware of any.

Comment: this does not give me the same download speed as http://www.speakeasy.net/speedtest/

Comment: hmmm. download speed vs transfer rate?