# measure data transfer rate with 200 simultaneous users

Tags: python, linux, networking, performance-testing

I have linux (Ubuntu) machine as a client. I want to measure data transfer rate when 200 users try to download files from my server at the same time.

Is there some python or linux tool for this? Or can you recommend an approach?

I saw [this speedcheck code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163408/python-speedtest-net-or-equivalent), and I can wrap it in threads, but I don't understand why the code there is so "complicated" and the block size changes all the time.

Comment: Why do you need 200 threads to download a file?  More threads won't make it go any faster when your internet link is your bottleneck.

Comment: i change threads to users. I need to see what will be the transfer rate when 200 user concurrently will try to download file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import threading
import time
import urllib2

block_sz = 8192
num_threads = 1
url = "http://192.168.1.1/bigfile2"
secDownload = 30

class DownloadFileThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        self.file_size_dl = 0


    def run(self):
        while True:
            buffer = self.u.read(block_sz)
            if not buffer:
                raise 'There is nothing to read. You should have bigger file or smaller time'

            self.file_size_dl += len(buffer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print 'Download from url ' + url + ' use in ' + str(num_threads)  + ' to download. test time ' + str(secDownload)  
        threads = []
        for i in range(num_threads):
            downloadThread = DownloadFileThread()
            downloadThread.daemon = True
            threads.append(downloadThread)
        for i in range(num_threads):
            threads[i].start()
        time.sleep(secDownload)

        sumBytes=0
        for i in range(num_threads):
            sumBytes = sumBytes +  threads[i].file_size_dl
        print sumBytes
        print str(sumBytes/(secDownload *1000000)) + 'MBps'
```

Answer (score 1):

I used [Mult-Mechanize](http://testutils.org/multi-mechanize/) recently to run some performance tests. It was fairly easy and worked pretty well.

Comment: i am familiar with it. i dont see how you can see the transfer rate because it measure transactions latency. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're talking about an actual dedicated server. For traffic graphs and so on I prefer to use [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/). It is a pretty complete monitoring application which builds you nice graphs using rrdtool. Examples are linked on the munin site: [full setup](http://munin.ping.uio.no/), [eth0 traffic graph](http://munin.ping.uio.no/ping.uio.no/bimbo.ping.uio.no/if_eth0.html).

The [new munin 2](http://demo.munin-monitoring.org/munin-monitoring.org/demo.munin-monitoring.org/index.html#network) is even more flashy, but I did not use it yet as it's not in my repos and I don't like to mess with perl applications.

Comment: i just need simple total check of my own server. i write my own code. i hope its ok. you can see the code in the answers.

Comment: @user1495181 Of course it's okay. Although munin is set up easily and quite powerful. And I love graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe 'ab' from apache ?

```
ab -n 1000 -c 200 [http[s]://]hostname[:port]/path
-n Number of requests to perform
-c Number of multiple requests to make at a time
```

It has many options, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html
 or man ab