# tracking the current http transfer in python

Tags: python, html, http, get

Hello I would like to do a simple bandwidth test. The size of the default html page is 10 MB. The upload speed of the server is 5 Mbps, so under no circumstances 10 MB can be completed in 10 seconds. My plan is to start time interval in get request and after 10 seconds later I should be able to get either percentage or amount of total bytes sent to one particular client. So my question here is how do I get the percentage or amount of total bytes?

Comment: is your code running on the client side or server side. So do you wan to measure the bandwidth from the server or from the client code.

Comment: it's a http server and client only has a web browser. So everything will be done on the server side.

Comment: We will need details then on your server-side setup. how are you running python is it mod wsgi, what is your webserver, what wsgi app are you using django or flask

Comment: It is not mod or anything, all I want to know is how to gather the amount of total bytes sent.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1**

So the simplest solution would be to use this [open source speedtest](http://www.brandonchecketts.com/open-source-speedtest) that will show in the browser the download speeds they are getting from your specific server. It will also show the upload speeds to your server. This particular solution uses php and perl on the server side. There is a related question [Python speedtest.net, or equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9163408/1699750) that didn't have an answer in the lines you are looking for.

**Approach 2**

You can do the download test using javascript and ajax which let you monitor the [download progress of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/399641/1699750) from the web browser. For the upload portion you also use the same technique of monitoring a [ajax upload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4856917/1699750).